# XEN Bootloader or Kernel error bootloader isn't executable / cannot locate kernel when using XM create

Tags: linux, xen

I am currently using Xen for installing VM guests however whenever we run

```
xm create -c /etc/xen/ks.test.cfg
```

we get;

```
Using config file "/etc/xen/ks.test.cfg".
Error: Bootloader isn't executable
```

The contents of ks.test.cfg are as follows;

```sh
# Configuration file for the Xen instance ks.test, created
# by xen-tools 3.8 on Thu Jan 31 16:18:09 2013.
#

#
#  Kernel + memory size
#
bootloader = '/usr/lib/xen/boot/hvmloader'
memory      = '512'

#
#  Disk device(s).
#
root        = '/dev/sda1 ro'
disk        = [
                  'file:/home/xen/domains/ks.test/disk.img,sda1,w',
              ]


#
#  Hostname
#
name        = 'ks.test'

#
#  Networking
#
vif         = [ 'ip=**.**.***.***,mac=**:**:**:**:**:**' ]

#
#  Behaviour
#
on_poweroff = 'destroy'
on_reboot   = 'restart'
on_crash    = 'restart'
```

Please note, I purposely *'d out the ip & mac.